# android bluetooth discovery: ACTION_FOUND happening after ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am implementing Bluetooth support via implementing a task which searches for devices in the background and provides a list when the search is complete. However, this list occasionally contains a `No devices found` entry (added only when `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` is received with no devices already in the list) before listing other devices!

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBlueToothInfoDiscoveryListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  /**
   * This is an overridden function called by the framework whenever there
   * is some broadcast message for Bluetooth info discovery listener
   */
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // When discovery finds a device
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
      // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
      BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed
      // already
      if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
        mNewBtDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
      }
    } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
      // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
      setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
      setTitle("device list");
      if (mNewBtDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
        String noDevices = "No devices found";
        mNewBtDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I don't expect `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` to ever come *before* a `ACTION_FOUND` event, so why would the `No devices found` string be added to the list before a device is located?

Comment: I had the same problem and my reply is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19433923/2701314

regards

Answer (score 2):

Simply because the discovery task has a timeout to prevent endless searched. So, in case there is no available device around, you'll get your "**No Devices found**"...