# Bluetooth: No broadcast for ACTION_FOUND or ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

This simple broadcastreceiver never receives anything. No discovered device from BluetoothDevice and no start/stop of discovery from `BluetoothAdapter`.

Earlier in the code, I check that Bluetooth is enabled and the `BluetoothAdapter` correctly lists the three paired devices. I've tried variations of unpairing them manually in the phone and I turn bluetooth visibility in the three remote devices on and off. But nothing is logged from my broadcast receiver. I start/stop discovery with layout buttons. `startDiscovery()` always returns `true`, `cancelDiscovery()` always returns false. The code is basically from the Android Bluetooth Dev Guide.

My code:

```
package intrax.three;

import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import intrax.three.R;

public class BtAct extends Activity {
    final String TAG = "BtAct";
    final int ENABLE_BLUETOOTH_REQ = 1;
    final String[] STATENAMES = {"Disconnected","Connecting","Connected","Disconnecting","STATE UNDEFINED","STATE UNDEFINED","STATE UNDEFINED","STATE UNDEFINED","STATE UNDEFINED","STATE UNDEFINED","Off","Turning on","On","Turning off"};
long discoveryStartTime = 0;

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
IntentFilter intentFilter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.btlayout);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    /* Device's own Bluetooth */
    if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBluetoothIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetoothIntent, ENABLE_BLUETOOTH_REQ);
        Log.v(TAG, "The device's own bluetooth is NOT enabled.");
    }
    else {
        Log.v(TAG, "The device's own bluetooth IS enabled.");
        String  btOwnAddress =  btAdapter.getAddress();
        String  btOwnName =         btAdapter.getName();
        int         btOwnState =        btAdapter.getState();
        Log.v(TAG, btOwnAddress+" "+btOwnName);
        Log.v(TAG, STATENAMES[btOwnState]);
    }

    /** List paired devices **/
    Log.v(TAG, "Check for paired devices:");
    discoveryStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> allPairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    Log.v(TAG, "It took "+(SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-discoveryStartTime+"ms to get paired devices. Starttime="+discoveryStartTime));
    if (allPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice pairedDevice : allPairedDevices) {
            Log.v(TAG, pairedDevice.getName()+" "+pairedDevice.getAddress()+" was found");
        }
    }

    /* Remote bluetooth */
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,0);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);

    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("ACTION_FOUND");
    intentFilter.addAction("ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED");
    intentFilter.addAction("ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED");

    /* User interface */
    Button bStartScan =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStartScan);
    bStartScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "intentReceiver="+intentReceiver);
            Log.v(TAG, "Discovery started");
            boolean bol = btAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Log.v(TAG, "Returned from discovery, start="+bol);
            Log.v(TAG, "Disc enabled="+btAdapter.isDiscovering());
        }
    });//END bStart
    Button bStopScan =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStopScan);
    bStopScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "bStopScan clicked");
            if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                 boolean bol = btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    Log.v(TAG, "Discovery canceled="+bol);
            };
            Log.v(TAG, "still discovering="+btAdapter.isDiscovering());
        }
    });//END bStop


}//END onCreate


private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {  // Abstract class
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent receivedIntent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Entered intentReceiver");
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(receivedIntent.getAction())) 
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "Found after="+(SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-discoveryStartTime));
            BluetoothDevice foundDevice = receivedIntent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.v(TAG, foundDevice.getName()+" "+foundDevice.getAddress()+" was found");
            BluetoothDevice foundDeviceClass = receivedIntent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_CLASS);
            Log.v(TAG, "BT class: "+foundDeviceClass.toString());
        }
        else if (btAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(receivedIntent.getAction())) {
            discoveryStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        }
        else if (btAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(receivedIntent.getAction())) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Discovery lasted: "+(SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-discoveryStartTime+"ms Starttime="+discoveryStartTime));
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "intentReceiver finished");
    }//END onReceive
};//END BroadcastReceiver

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultIntent);
    switch(requestCode) {
    case ENABLE_BLUETOOTH_REQ:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Bluetooth successfully enabled by request");
        }
        else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Bluetooth was not enabled. Finishing.");
            finish();
        }
    }//END switch
}//END onActivityResult

protected void onResume() {
    Log.v(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
    Log.v(TAG, "intentReceiver="+intentReceiver);
}

protected void onPause() {
    Log.v(TAG, "onPause");
    super.onPause();
    if (intentReceiver != null) {
        Log.v(TAG, "intentReceiver to be unregistered");
        unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
    }
}
}//END Class
```

EDIT AGAIN:
Changed to:

```
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
```

The following is logged when I click on a physical button on one of the paired remote devices (a headphone), although still nothing is logged as received. I suppose that it is some other app or the OS, it's not my app:

```
02-24 14:12:23.096: D/InputMethodManager(28164): dispatchKeyEvent
02-24 14:12:23.096: V/InputMethodManager(28164): DISPATCH KEY: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@47c89938
02-24 14:12:23.156: D/InputMethodManager(28164): dispatchKeyEvent
02-24 14:12:23.156: V/InputMethodManager(28164): DISPATCH KEY: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@47c89938
```

Comment: dont use the intent filters in your activity inmanifest, infact use them to register inside your code

Comment: I had them both in code and manifest. But removing them from the manifest doesn't change anything. intentFilter = new IntentFilter(); intentFilter.addAction("ACTION_FOUND"); intentFilter.addAction("ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED"); intentFilter.addAction("ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED");

Comment: have you added any bluetooth permission in your manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`

Comment: user-permissions are there, also for BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, before the application tag.

Comment: have you called `registerReceiver` in your code too?

Comment: Yes, right after setting intentFilters I do registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter); Next question I make, I'll post ALL code, sorry.

Comment: yes, post your all code together by editing this question or add a new one. and send me the link

Comment: So, now the entire activity is reposted in the original question. I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

seems like you are not registering broadcast receivers in your code:

```
IntentFilter intFilter = new IntentFilter();
intFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
intFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
intFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
```

in your onResume:

```
registerReceiver(intentReceiver , intFilter);
```

in onPause:

```
unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
```

Comment: I do, see edit in my question now. I've also tried to register it in onCreate too

Comment: you are entering wrong action strings in your intent filter.... see the way i'm adding...

Comment: You are entering as **intentFilter.addAction("ACTION_FOUND");** which is wrong. Correct way is `intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);`

Comment: Ofcourse, thanks! But STILL it doesn't change a thing! btAdapter.isDiscovering() never returns true. But I noticed that the log reacts on clicking on a paired device, but not my app.

Comment: are you getting bluetooth events like ACTION_FOUND, ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED and ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED correctly?

Comment: No, I never got that. It should've been logged. When I click to start discovery, this is logged. 02-24 14:34:11.076: V/BtAct(28491): Returned from discovery, start=true
02-24 14:34:11.076: V/BtAct(28491): Disc enabled=false Then nothing more is logged by my app unless I click again with same result.

Comment: just a silly question but still thought to confirm :) are you using Emulator for this?

Comment: why are you having these lines? `Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,0);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);`. Just remove/comment them

Comment: No :-) I do use a physical device. I'll start over from scratch and hope for better luck. And the "discoverable" lines were suggested by Emel Elias here below. It makes no difference for my problem whether they are there or not.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problema, follow my solution:

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(intent.getAction()) && sBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
```

After i cancel my discovery and if even so the BroadcastReceiver catch BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND, the discovery flag will be "false".

Works for me.

Any doubt, im here.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that device is discoverable in settings. You can also do it by firing an intent like this:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(
    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,0);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

in `onCreate()`
and then the above code

Comment: I added your code, but still doesn't help. After .startDiscovery(), isDiscovering() returns false. That can't be right.

Comment: AFAIK, this is wrong.  Making the local device discoverable to other devices is not the same as telling the local device to discover others.  [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) specifically mentions both modes.

Answer (score 1):

**The Discovery issue**

Not completely related to your question but a good note nontheless, is that since discovery is a "intensive process" it happens when the scheduler wants it to. If your code is something along the lines of :

```
startDiscovery();
while(adapter.isDiscovering()){
   // Something Here
}
```

The code is just going to skip the while block because it hasn't started discovery yet. A quick and certainly dirty fix is to do the following:

```
startDiscovery();
while(!adapter.isDiscovering());
while(adapter.isDiscovering()){
   // Something Here
}
```

That is totally nasty and should not work but does. *I don't know either.*

(Unrelated: Does anybody know why the ACTION_FOUND event never fire?, I looked at my log in adb and using the bluetooth options menu, saw a action.DISCOVERY_STARTED then some time later a action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED, but no FOUND event, only a `BluetoothEventManager: DeviceFoundHandler created new CachedBluetoothDevice`)

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, it seems ACTION_FOUND is never fired because it never found anything? Discovery started, finsihed, but found nothing.